# Incorrect values assigned to a member of a structure

Tags: c

I have a structure

```
 struct services {
 char *actived[50];
 char *disactived[50];
 };
```

and a function :

```
void servicesInfo(struct services *services_i) {
FILE *fp;
int status;
char *tmp;
const char *actived_cmd ="/usr/sbin/service --status-all | awk '/[+]/{ print $4  }'" ;

fp = popen(actived_cmd, "r");
int i=0;
while (fgets(tmp, 1024, fp)){
    printf("service %s\n", tmp);
    (services_i->actived)[i]=tmp;
    i++;
}
status = pclose(fp);
```

}

when i call the function

```
 struct services services_i;
 servicesInfo(&services_i);
```

all is fine and all services printed, but if this code

```
for (i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
{
    printf("service i=%d %s\n",i,services_i.actived[i] );       
}
```

print just the last value (uvrandom)

Comment: There is no memory allocated to `tmp`. So `fgets(tmp, 1024, fp)` is doomed. MSVC gives me *"warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'tmp' used"*. Enable warnings.

Comment: In addition, `(services_i->actived)[i]=tmp;` that will also not work unless `tmp` is dynamically allocated for *each* `fgets`. Otherwise you only get the last value copied into `tmp` because all the `activated` entries point to the same buffer. But of course, as pointed out already, your program has Undefined Behaviour because no memory is allocated for `tmp` in the first place. And before you ask, the reason you are still able to print even the last value is by chance/accident as Undefined Behaviour means that the actual result is unpredictable and not guaranteed.

Comment: You might want to enable warnings on your compiler and step through your code in debug mode. The warnings in your case are very descriptive.

Comment: thanks @kaylum ,I've checked it

Comment: @user3011195 does "I checked" mean that because the value you see is correct, you are brushing off that experienced programmer's comment? Another day, another machine, you'll get segfault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read up on C pointer and memory allocation. There are two misunderstandings here:

1. `tmp` is not, as it is written, a string buffer. It is just a string pointer. It can only be assigned to point to strings that are allocated somewhere else, and not contain the string itself.
2. You are just copying the pointer to `actived` (which by the way probably should be spelled `activated`). This means that all `actived` pointers all point to the same as `tmp` does, which is always the same, since tmp is never changed (and also has uninitialized value).

I suggest you use `tmp = malloc(1024)`. Don't forget to use `free(services_i.actived[i])` when you don't need them anymore.

I also suggest making an array of structs instead of a struct of arrays, to make it more logical.

Comment: Upvoted because it's better than other answer, which besides misunderstanding the question, has the wrong definition for `main`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some example code of how to assign a value to structure:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct date {           /* global definition of type date */
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;
};

main()
{

    struct date  today;

    today.month = 10;
    today.day = 14;
    today.year = 1995;

    printf("Todays date is %d/%d/%d.\n", \
        today.month, today.day, today.year );
}
```

Comment: Err... very nice but I think OP's problem is not *how* to assign a value to a `struct` field, but *the value that is being assigned*, see above comments, which show a) why it is *undefind behaviour* and b) why each `struct` field will contain the same pointer  == most recent data.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the title, that was misleading.

Comment: Upvotes? I guess the answer is technically correct if only the question title is read.